# hipster - importing JDL

Tags: jhipster, jdl

I'm new to jhipster. so I'm sorry if the answer is obvious.

I'm trying to import my JDL with the command :

```
import-jdl ~/Downloads/jhipster-jdl.jh  --debug
```

my JDL:

```
entity Package{
    origin String,
    destination String,
    amORpm String,
    department Integer,
    weight Long,
    barcode Long
}

entity Supplier {
    regionName String required
}
entity Mission{
    dueDate Instant required
}
entity Seller {
    streetAddress String,
    postalCode String,
    city String,
    stateProvince String,
    phoneNumber String
}
entity WareHouse{
    regionName String 
}
entity Timer {
    firstName String,
    lastName String,
    email String,
    phoneNumber String,
    hiringDate Instant required
}
entity GraphDataWeight {
    effort Long
}
relationship OneToOne{
    Mission {missionId} to Package
}
relationship OneToMany {
    Supplier {packageId} to Package
    Seller {sellerId} to Mission
    Timer {timerId} to Mission
    WareHouse {timerId} to Timer
    GraphDataWeight {sellerId1} to Seller
    GraphDataWeight {sellerId2} to Seller
}


paginate all with infinite-scroll
paginate all with pagination
dto * with mapstruct

 Set service options to all except few
service all with serviceImpl 
 Set an angular suffix
angularSuffix * with mySuffix
```

the error I get:

```
The JDL is being parsed.
DEBUG! Error:
Error: The entity must be valid in order to be added.
Errors: The entity name cannot be a reserved keyword
```

tried all options that I found to fix it but I get the same error
at the begging I had an enum but I changed it just to get it to work. but I still get this error
I don't see any reserved words that I know of

thanks in advance for ur time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call an entity **Package** since it is a reserved keyword.

You also need to remove or comment out **Set service options to all except few** and **Set an angular suffix** to make it work.